# How to make scrollTop Scrolldon Responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, responsive-design, scrolltop

I want this function to work right when I minimize my website (responsive). 
When the website gets smaller the scrollTop funcion doesn't go to the right place I want it to go (section2).

My code:

```
function scrolldownsection2() {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $("#section2").offset().top + 200 
    }, 1000);
}
```

The website has 3 responive redesign:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 72.75em)
@media screen and (max-width: 59.25em)
@media screen and (max-width: 48em)
```

I want the scroll  to adjust to every single one. Does anyone can help me? :)

Thank You!!!